# Yup validation test UUID or certain string

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have a string which can be a string like "System" or uuid (check 36 bytes for simplicity), how can I use Yup to validate it?

I had tried `Yup.mixed().oneOf([string().min(36).max(36), "System"])`, but seems the uuid part failed.

Any idea?